# Azure DevOps/VSTS always reports "DETACHED HEAD" on a clean repository

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

Friends,

I am now getting tired of Azure DevOps/VSTS. Jenkins was much better and still is, just my organization wants to use Azure DevOps.

I have a mystery which I need assistance to solve.

The following is the out of my repo from my laptop, it has no untracked or uncommitted changes.

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/xxx/terraformvsts.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/xxx/terraformvsts.git (push)
```

Guess, what, Azure Devops always complains that it has "DETACHED HEAD" , at every build execution.

Note the following from "Checkout" phase:

```
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2076875Z Note: checking out 'aad90fceecf39a7731c356ebfe2b547ddbce99e6'.
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2076992Z 
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2077872Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2077939Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078179Z state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078345Z 
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078389Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078683Z do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078717Z 
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078933Z   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2078966Z 
2019-02-05T05:55:33.2079004Z HEAD is now at aad90fc Clean Repository
```

The checkout phase for Build pipeline is like below:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? should I not do checkout? or one of the config settings in the Build pipelines should be amended?

Comment: Like the answer, this is the behavior of Azure DevOps builds. what is the issue? why is not good for you?

Comment: I don't like it either. It's not intuitive, neither some partners know it all and it's not flexible.The Microsoft way is complex and full of unnecessary steps. Not to mention that advanced things are restrict to their shell, which only runs on Windows.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - By browsing the text of the question, I reckon the issue is "Azure Devops always complains that it has "DETACHED HEAD"", wouldn't you agree? I also reckon the OP, like anyone else, would prefer to be on the main branch (unless a specific branch is provided in the checkout instruction). But alas, the checkout instruction params are a textbook example of poor design (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not complaining, this is how Azure DevOps works. I see on all builds, on all repos. nothing is wrong.

Comment: @Edward Thomson, Noticed you edited this answer for ADO to Azure DevOps.  Is there some other shortened naming Microsoft prefer us to use if it isn't ADO?  It was usually easy when it was Visual Studio Team Services to just use VSTS in conversation, but calling it 'Azure DevOps Server' in casual conversation is a little too wordy.

Comment: I think ADO is the "standard" name for it

Comment: No, we don't have an abbreviation for "Azure DevOps" - things like "ADO" are confusing, since there's already an "ADO.net".  But "Azure DevOps" is the same number of syllables as "VSTS".  *shrug*

Comment: people are going to shorten it, whether you like it or not, and guess what, nobody is going to call it devops ;) @EdwardThomson

Comment: Indeed, I can't stop people.  And no, nobody should call it "DevOps".  But it's worth mentioning that we call the different products by their own name.  We don't do builds in "Azure DevOps", we do builds in _Azure Pipelines_ (or, yes, just _Pipelines_).  We really only talk about Azure DevOps when we're talking about the full suite.

Comment: but we are not at microsoft here, right? :) people make short names for stuff.

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew that this is normal or not wrong. Proceeding with actual challenge task.

Comment: Historically ADO = ActiveX Data Objects; It's the technology used for database interrogation and persistence prior to ORMs such as EF and NHibernate. Since it has all that baggage already attached to it, ADO is already considered "in use", so we need to use something else. AD = Active Directory, so we can't use that. VSTS is the previous version, Visual Studio Online wasn't on-point enough. The irony is that it's reinforcing the misconception that DevOps = just CI/CD pipelines which is wrong.

Comment: Just want to chip on on the abbriviation part: we sometimes use AzDO.

Comment: AzureDevOps => ADOPS, ADEPS

Answer (score 11):

This is how Azure DevOps Pipelines is designed.

If you still need to checkout "that" branch (or any other specific branch), you can add a task:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  inputs:
    script: 'git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

Comment: We can use this task but there could be concerns as pointed out in the issue - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1980

Comment: Note that `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` only contains, e.g., `foobar` for branch `username/foobar`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables. Use `git name-rev --name-only $(Build.SourceBranch)` to get the full branch name.

Answer (score 6):

Let's be distinct about the issues.

- The branch being used is referred to as $(Build.SourceBranch) in the Azure pipelines.
- Azure pipelines detach the working branch from the remote branch.
- Azure pipelines delete the *reference* to the remote branch
- Checking out a local copy of the current version of the upstream branch, suitable for doing "git push" operations to, can be done this way.

==========================================================

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
   git fetch --all
   git switch $(basename $(Build.SourceBranch))
```

==========================================================

Additional desirable settings may include:

```
   git config --local user.email "username@example.com"
   git config --local user.name "User Name"
```

Comment: Why "basename"? Also didn't work, the code didn't run inside AzureDevOps pipeline

Answer (score 1):

To checkout the source branch, run this step:

```
- script: |
    source=$(Build.SourceBranch)
    git checkout ${source#"refs/heads/"}
```

A solution with `git name-rev --name-only $(Build.SourceBranch)` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I need to update this. The "git switch" fails in an Azure Pipeline environment because not only is the working git repo detached, but Azure pipelines delete the reference to the upstream branch in the working git configuraion. Use something like this instead.

============================================

```
steps:
- checkout: self   clean: true   persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    git fetch --all
    git branch -D `basename $(Build.SourceBranch)` || true
    git switch `basename $(Build.SourceBranch)`
```