# How can I push latest commits to external remote origin a devops build pipeline?

Tags: git, azure, build, azure-devops

I have 2 separate code repos containing the same code, origin 1 and origin 2. Our development team only pushes new code to origin 1, but I need to build our code from origin 2.

How can I keep the two origin remotes up to date automatically using Azure Devops CI?

My thought is to use a Azure Devops Build Pipeline connected to Origin 1 and in the build add Origin 2 as a remote, and then push the changes, but the devops pipeline seems to detach the head when cloning the latest changes.

Any idea how to automate this?

Right now I have:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Adding git remote
      git remote add origin2 https://myRemoteoriginGit
      git push origin2 my-branch
    failOnStderr: true
```

Comment: Could you add more details about the progress that you made? What is the output of the yml you paste in the question? Is there any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea how to automate this?

In Origin 1 pipeline, you could try the following script in **PowerShell** Task.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $branch="$(Build.SourceBranch)".replace("refs/heads/","")
      git remote add Reponame https://PAT@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/reponame
      git checkout $branch
      git push Reponame $branch -f
```

You could set **All** branches to trigger this build ([CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)).

Then  this script will  update the changes to the corresponding branch in Origin 2.

> The devops pipeline seems to detach the head when cloning the latest changes.

According to your description, i guess what you see is this text：

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by switching
>   back to a branch.

If yes, this is how Azure DevOps works. Nothing is wrong.

Here is [a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528776/azure-devops-vsts-always-reports-detached-head-on-a-clean-repository), you could refer to it.

Hope this helps.